# What is the expected determinant of a symmetric $2\times2$ matrix, whose three elements are distinct and draw from$ [-n,n]$

Tags: probability

> The symmetric matrix has three elements:
>   \begin{pmatrix} A&B\\ B&C \end{pmatrix}
>   $A,B$ and $C$ are integers draw randomly from $\{-n,-n+1,\dots,n-1,n\}$, $n\ge2$ and they are distinct with each other. What is the expected determinant of this matrix?

I have no clue how to do this, this seems multiple random variables, I don't know how to attack this problem systematically.

### Edit

Computer run give the result of $n =[2,10]$:

`-2.49301 -4.66934 -7.52694 -11.0413 -15.18877 -19.97767 -25.64429 -31.6045 -38.66689`

Therefore we have a correct answer which is $$\displaystyle-\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$ However, an more easier to understand answer is still very welcomed.

Code:

```
import random
N = 100000
for n in range(2,11):
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,N):
        a,b,c=random.sample(range(-n,n+1),3)
        total += a*c-b*b
    print(total/N,end = ' ')
```

Comment: [-n,n] you mean all the integers in there, or every number. Continuous or discrete?

Comment: @JimmyR. Integers.

Comment: @JimmyR. Why delete it, you can keep it and label that the answer is for three independent matrix. I want to see that part too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may calculate $E(AC)$ without thinking of $B$ (you first pick randomly $A,C$ distinct and don't worry about $B$, the first double sum below is zero):
$$ E(AC) =\frac{1}{(2n+1)2n} \left( \sum_{a=-n}^n \sum_{c=-n}^n ac - \sum_{a=-n}^n  a^2\right) =  -\frac{1}{(2n+1)2n}\frac{2n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}= -\frac{n+1}{6}$$
and  then for $E(B^2)$ you need not worry about $A,C$, so:
$$ E(B^2) =\frac{1}{(2n+1)} \left( \sum_{a=-n}^n  b^2\right) =  \frac{1}{(2n+1)}\frac{2n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}= \frac{2n(n+1)}{6}$$
Finally (with a non-zero probability of having done some errors along the way):
$$E(\det S)= E(AC-B^2)=-\frac{(n+1)(1+2n)}{6}$$

Comment: Why $E(B^2)$ not worry about $A$ and $C$? When AC are chosen, B can't choose the value of A and C

Comment: Yeah, you're right, silly me ! $\mathbb P(A=i\wedge C=j)=\mathbb P(A=-i\wedge C=j)$, **except** for $i=-j$ !!! So $\mathbb E(AC)$ is not zero.

Comment: @fizis You change the 'point of view'. In fact $(A,B,C)$ is a distinct triple selected from a given set of integers. You may view this as selecting them in whatever order you want (which may ease the calculation, as in the above).

Comment: Under this point of view, you have $(2n+1)2n(2n-1)$ possible choice of ABC, and how you calculate the sum of determinant of all these matrixes?

Comment: Your answer is correct, however I still don't understand...

Comment: Don't know if this helps? But the point is that expectation is linear so $E(\det S)=E(AC)-E(B^2)$ and then you may use the probabilistic model that suits best in the calculation. This is very often used in proba as it sometimes simplifies enormously the calculation. So in the calculation of $E B^2$ you think of the choices as follows: Picking a distinct triple $A,B,C$ you may pick in whatever order you want (and which suits you best). So pick first $B$ and then $A,C$. But then you don't care about $A,C$ so you only use the proba for $B$.

Comment: I think I understand a little bit about your explanation. When we calculate the quantity $E(B)$, what we need to know is the distribution probability of each $B=k$, but they are same, regardless of what $A$ and $C$ takes. Now if we want to calculate the quantity $E(ABC)$, in which three elements all occurs, then we need to think about the restriction. For $E(AC)$, the restriction is just that $A\neq B$, but for E(ABC) the restriction is $A\neq B$, $B\neq C$, $A\neq C$.

Comment: Indeed, the calculation of E(ABC) is more complicated as it needs all the information of the elements being distinct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the notation. When you write $B$ you actually mean $B$ conditional on $B\neq A=a$, which is not uniformly distributed on $[-n,n]$ but on $[-n,n]\backslash\{a\}$. Similarly, conditional on the values of $A=a,B=b$ the random variable $C$ is uniformly distributed on $[-n,n]\backslash\{a,b\}$. So, actually when you write $B$ you abuse notation for $B\mid A=a$ and when you write $C$ you abuse notation for $C\mid A=a, B=b$, plus the condition that $B\neq A\neq C$. All that said, you can solve it by conditioning, as is your intuition:

\begin{align}\mathbb E[AC]-\mathbb E[B^2]&=\sum_{a=-n}^n\left(\mathbb E\left[AC\mid A=a\right]-\mathbb E\left[B^2\mid A=a\right]\right)P(A=a)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{a=-n}^n\left(a\cdot \mathbb E\left[C\mid A=a\right]-\mathbb E\left[B^2\mid A=a\right]\right)\end{align} with 
\begin{align}\mathbb E[B^2\mid A=a]&=\frac1{2n}\sum_{b=-n,b\neq a}^nb^2=\frac{1}{2n}\left(\sum_{b=-n}^nb^2-a^2\right)=\frac{1}{2n}\left(2\sum_{b=-n}^nb^2-a^2\right)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{2n}\left(2\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-a^2\right)=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{a^2}{2n}\end{align} and (now we must condition also on $B$):
\begin{align}\mathbb E[C\mid A=a]&=\sum_{b=-n,b\neq a}^n\mathbb E[C\mid A=a,B=b]P(B=b)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{b=-n,b\neq a}^n\left(\sum_{c=-n,c\neq a,b}^n c\cdot\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)=\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}\sum_{b=-n,b\neq a}^n\left(\sum_{c=-n}^nc-b-a\right)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}\sum_{b=-n,b\neq a}^n(0-b-a)=-\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}\left(\sum_{b=-n}^n(b+a)-(a+a)\right)\\[0.3cm]&=-\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}\left(0+(2n+1)a-2a\right)=-\frac{a}{2n}\end{align} And now, we substitute in the first equation to get 
\begin{align}\mathbb E[AC]-\mathbb E[B^2]&=\sum_{a=-n}^n\left(\mathbb E\left[AC\mid A=a\right]-\mathbb E\left[B^2\mid A=a\right]\right)P(A=a)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{a=-n}^na\cdot \mathbb E\left[C\mid A=a\right]-\mathbb E\left[B^2\mid A=a\right]\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{a=-n}^n\left(a\left(-\frac{a}{2n}\right)-\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{a^2}{2n}\right)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{a=-n}^n\left(\frac{a^2}{2n}-\frac{a^2}{2n}-\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{2n+1}\cdot(2n+1)\cdot\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=-\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If we do not require that $A\neq B\neq C$, then the random variables $A,B,C$ are independent and distributed [discrete uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) on $\{-n,-n+1,\dots, -1, 0, 1, \dots, n-1,n \}$. Hence, $$\mathbb E[A]=\mathbb E[B]=\mathbb E[C]=\frac{n+(-n)}{2}=0$$ and $$Var(A)=Var(B)=Var(C)=\frac{(n-(-n)+1)^2-1}{12}=\frac{(2n+1)^2-1}{12}$$
Now, if we denote the symmetric matrix with $S$, we have $$\det(S)=AC-B^2$$ hence
\begin{align}\mathbb E[\det(S)]&=\mathbb E[AC-B^2]=^{A,B,C \text{ are independent} }\\[0.2cm]&=\mathbb E[A]\mathbb E[C]-\mathbb E[B^2]=0\cdot0-\mathbb E[B^2]=-\mathbb E[B^2]\end{align} Recall that 
\begin{align}Var(B)&=\mathbb E[B^2]-\left(\mathbb E[B]\right)^2\\[0.2cm] \iff-\mathbb E[B^2]&=-Var(B)-\left(\mathbb E[B]\right)^2=-\frac{(2n+1)^2-1}{12}-0=\frac{n(n+1)}{3}\end{align} to obtain 
\begin{align}\mathbb E[\det(S)]=\frac{n(n+1)}{3}\end{align}

Comment: But they are distinct from each other, I think they has a little dependence..

Comment: Yes, they are different. I think the statement in my question is not rigors

Comment: The independent I mean is really means that we have three "independent" elements in a symmetric matrix...

Comment: @Jimmy R. : your result and mine are the same (which only comes from the fact that no matter how you consider it, $\mathbb E(AC)=0$), except that you seem ta have mixed up the minus signs in the computation of $\mathbb E(B^2)$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Thanks a lot, you are right. I think that in your answer, when calculating $\mathbb E[B^2]$ you have somehow to exclude that $B=A=C$, otherwise it does not seem correct. What do you think?

Comment: "Hence $E[B\mid A]=\ldots=0$" No, what you compute there is actually $E[B]=0$ (and this conclusion can be reached more easily), not $E[B\mid A]$ which is simply $E[B\mid A]=-\frac{A}{2n}$ by the computation of $E[B\mid A=a]$.

Comment: "order of drawing A,B,C matters" Wrong guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think the beginning should be like Jimmy R started : by linearity of expectation,
$$\mathbb E(AC-B^2)=\mathbb E(AC)-\mathbb E(B^2)$$
Now $A$ and $C$ are not independent ($\mathbb P(A=i)=\mathbb P(C=j)=\frac{1}{2n+1}$, but $\mathbb P(A=i \wedge C=j)=\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}$), but as $\mathbb P(A=i \wedge C=j)=\mathbb P(A=-i \wedge C=j)$, it should be clear that $\mathbb E(AC)=0$.

Now for $\mathbb E(B^2)$, I find :
$$\mathbb E(B^2)=\sum_{k=-n}^n k^2\mathbb P(B=k)=\frac{2}{2n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{2}{2n+1}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\frac{n(n+1)}{3}$$
So if my reasoning is correct, 
$$\mathbb E\left(\det\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B & C \end{pmatrix}\right)=-\frac{n(n+1)}{3}$$
for the given distribution of values $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: "$\mathbb P(A=i \wedge C=j)=\mathbb P(A=-i \wedge C=j)$" Not if $i=\pm j$. As a  consequence "it should be clear that $\mathbb E(AC)=0$" does not hold.